# Posting MainThread Runnables Memory Leak Safe Android

Tags: android, memory-leaks, runnable

I have a question regarding memory leaks. I have the below anonymous class. As you might know anonymous class hold reference from the outside object(here is Activity). Does this code causes memory leak or not? In case of orientation this will hold the old activity. Right?

Thank you

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{


recyclerview.post(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    // Notify adapter with appropriate notify methods
    adapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(curSize, allContacts.size() - 1);
}
});

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this code causes memory leak or not?

Not really. That `Runnable` should be executed within a millisecond or so — otherwise, you have bigger issues.

If that `Runnable` would be around for an extended period of time, *then* you might have a memory leak.

Comment: And how should i know if this runnable stick around for an extended period of time? If for some reason main thread wont be able to execute this runnable before a rotation happens there will be a memory leak. But even so, how can i control this? I dont think there is a workaround

Comment: @Nick: "And how should i know if this runnable stick around for an extended period of time?" -- a call to `post()` will not result in a long-lived `Runnable`, unless there are severe bugs in your app that cause the main application thread to be busy for a long time. "If for some reason main thread wont be able to execute this runnable before a rotation happens there will be a memory leak" -- that will be due to a bug in your code that is tying up the main application thread. "how can i control this?" -- fix the bug in your code that is tying up the main application thread.

Comment: If something kills the activity before runnable executed there will be a memory leak